# Reuse code that performs async code and posts back to the UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a class with 6 async methods, each one should call a blocking method. (meaning, a blocking method is posted on a background thread, and the result is posted on the ui thread)

I find my self writing the following code 6 times (1 per each async method), having only the blocking method and 'result' object type different.

```
    mBackgroundThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            final String result = myBlockingMethod();

            mUIHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                     //use result on UI thread
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

- mBackgroundThreadHandler - a handler for a background thread
- mUIHandler - a handler for the ui thread

Is there a "pretty" way to reuse this code?

Comment: You can post the result in onPostExecute of the aynChronous task as well

Answer (score 1):

While still a bit lengthy, maybe this could help?

```
abstract class BgTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final String result = getResult();
        mUIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                processResult(result);
            }
        });
    }

    abstract String getResult();

    abstract void processResult(String result);

}
```

With the above class, the `mBackgroundThreadHandler` invocation becomes

```
mBackgroundThreadHandler.post(new BgTask() {
    @Override
    String getResult() {
        return myBlockingMethod();
    }

    @Override
    void processResult(String result) {
        // UI magic.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you probably should look into doing custom handlers, instead of just posting Runnables to them

the UI custom handler

```
Handler mUIHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){

   public void handleMessage (Message msg){
       switch(msg.what){
           case 0: // action 0,
               doResultZero(msg.obj);
               break;
           case 1: // action 1
               break;
           case 2: // action 2 
               break;
       }
   }
};
```

the background handler

```
Handler mBackgroundThreadHandler = new Handler( /* insert here the background looper */){

   public void handleMessage (Message msg){
       switch(msg.what){
           case 0: // action 0 
               msg.obj = executeActionZero();
               mUIHandler.sendMessage(msg);
               break;
           case 1: // action 1
               break;
           case 2: // action 2 
               break;
       }
   }
};
```

so, to start the process you do:

```
Message m = new Message();
m.what = 0;
mBackgroundThreadHandler.sendMessage(m);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can use the following class

```
public class RunnableOnBackgroudAndResultOnUI {

    private Handler mBackgroundThreadHandler; 
    private Handler mUIHandler;

    public RunnableOnBackgroudAndResultOnUI(Handler backgroundThreadHandler, Handler uIHandler) {
        mBackgroundThreadHandler = backgroundThreadHandler;
        mUIHandler = uIHandler;
    }

    public void run(final Runnable background, final Runnable ui) {
        mBackgroundThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                background.run();
                mUIHandler.post(ui);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and execute it like this

```
RunnableOnBackgroudAndResultOnUI runnableOnBackgroudAndResultOnUI = new RunnableOnBackgroudAndResultOnUI(mBackgroundThreadHandler, mUIHandler);

runnableOnBackgroudAndResultOnUI.run(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // run on background 

                }
            }, new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // run on ui

                }
            });
        }
    });
```